# How to fix "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'int'"

Tags: python

When I was running the following code in a function, I encountered the following error. However, when I run these lines, there is no error. 
The error appears at Line 185, TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'int'

Line 183 was my original code, which includes a dictionary. But now I'm not using dictionary anymore, whey the error is about dict??

```
183 #    N_layer = inputs["N_layer"]
184     N_layer = 18
185     n_uw = np.zeros((N_layer + 2), dtype=int)
186     n_dw = np.zeros((N_layer + 2), dtype=int)
187     n_gas = np.zeros((N_layer + 2), dtype=int)
```

The result should be array of zeros.

Comment: The code works. You might wanna try the same once again. Maybe `N_layer` wasn't overwritten

Comment: Are you using some notebook, where you have edited, but not saved?

Comment: I finally ran it after I restarted the entire anaconda. However, before that I have saved the file already. That is weird.